# Python sympy solve with functions

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I im trying to define at what flow "pressure_hill" are equal to "pressure_returnline" in function def calculateflow(Q):
im trying to use sympy solve but get error message below.

pressure_returnlie and pressure_hill are calculating a pressure drop that depends on flowvalue from water. I know that both will have the same pressure drop and I want to calculate what flow I have in each pipe.

When running the code I get TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

Is there a better way than using sympy solver?

Thanks // Sebastian

```
import numpy as np
import fluids
from scipy import stats

# #input h and D0
# h = 100 # mm
D0 = 149# mm
# flow = 5/60 #m3/min
# density = 999 #kg/m3
pi = 3.1416
# mu = 1E-3 # viscosity
# length = 10 # meter
# #calculation

def valve_pos(pos,control_sig,time):## Change / Secound
 
    cntrl_max = 254
    cntrl_min = 1
    cntrl_mid = 127
    
    time_forw = 1
    time_back = 1.5
    
    time_forw_min = 6
    time_back_min = 5
    
    min_pos = 5
    max_pos = 149
    cntrl_time = 0
    cntrl_time_min = 0
    way = 1

    if control_sig == cntrl_mid:
        return 0
    
    if control_sig > cntrl_mid:
        cntrl_time = time_forw
        cntrl_time_min = time_forw_min
        way = 1
        
    else:
        cntrl_time = time_back
        cntrl_time_min = time_back_min
        way = -1
            
    coeff = stats.linregress([cntrl_min,cntrl_mid,cntrl_max],[-1,0,1])
    rate = ((max_pos - min_pos) / cntrl_time) * (control_sig*coeff[0] + coeff[1]) * time
    rate_min = ((max_pos - min_pos) / cntrl_time_min) * way * time
    
    if abs(rate) < abs(rate_min):
        rate = rate_min
    
    if ((pos + rate) > max_pos) & (way > 0):
        rate = 0
        
    if ((pos - rate) < min_pos) & (way < 0):
        rate = 0
    
    return rate
    
    
def velocity(D0, flow):
    d = D0/1000
    area = (d**2*pi)/4
    w0 = flow/area # flow velocity m/s
    return w0

def knife_valve_pressure_loss (h,D0, density, flow):
    
    w0 = velocity(D0,flow)

    if h/D0 < 0.9 and h/D0 >= 0.2:
        a = np.array([7.661175,-72.63827,345.7625,-897.8331,1275.939,-938.8331,278.8193])
        i = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
        dzeta = np.exp(2.3*sum(a*(h/D0)**i))
    elif h/D0 >= 0.9:
        dzeta = 0.6 - 0.6 * (h/D0)
    elif h/D0 < 0.2 and h/D0 >= 0.0:
        dzeta = 13114 * (h/D0)**2 - 5216.1 * h/D0 + 553.17
    else:
        print ('formula cannot be used for this h/D0')
        return 0
    pressure_loss = dzeta * density * 0.5 * w0**2
    if pressure_loss < 0:
        pressure_loss = 0

    return pressure_loss/100000


def pipe_losses(D0,flow,density,length,mu= 1E-3):
    w0 = velocity(D0,flow)
    Re = fluids.Reynolds(V=w0, D=D0/1000, rho=1000, mu=mu)
    fd = fluids.friction_factor(Re, eD=1E-5/0.05)
    K = fluids.K_from_f(fd=fd, L=length, D=D0/1000)
    K += fluids.exit_normal()
    K += 4*fluids.bend_rounded(Di=D0/1000, angle=90, fd=fd)
    K += 3.6
    pressure_loss_pipe_fittings = fluids.dP_from_K(K, rho=density, V=w0)/100000
    liftheight_loss = 2/10.2
    return pressure_loss_pipe_fittings + liftheight_loss

def pressure_hill(flow, h = 149, length = 17, D0 = 139, density = 999):
    p_valve = knife_valve_pressure_loss (h,D0, density, flow)
    p_system = pipe_losses(D0,flow,density,length)
    return p_valve + p_system
    
def pressure_returnline(flow, h = 149, length = 1, D0 = 139, density = 999):
    p_valve = knife_valve_pressure_loss (h,D0, density, flow)
    p_system = pipe_losses((76/1000),flow,density,0.5)
    return p_valve + p_system

def calculateflow(Q):
    from sympy import symbols, solve, Eq, Symbol
       
    x,y = symbols('x,y')
    sol = solve(pressure_hill(x) - pressure_returnline(y) ,(x,y))

    sol

calculateflow(0.1)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-59-42d41eef9605>", line 1, in <module>
    calculateflow(0.1)

  File "system_losses.py", line 122, in calculateflow
    sol = solve(pressure_hill(x) - pressure_returnline(y) ,(x,y))

  File "system_losses.py", line 109, in pressure_hill
    p_valve = knife_valve_pressure_loss (h,D0, density, flow)

  File "system_losses.py", line 90, in knife_valve_pressure_loss
    if pressure_loss < 0:

  File "relational.py", line 398, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Comment: you can't use a sympy expression in an `if`

Comment: Also, when `pressure_loss` is a numpy array (in the case of  `if 0.2 <= h/D0 < 0.9:`), you can't write  `if pressure_loss < 0: pressure_loss = 0`. In that case you could use something like `pressure_loss = np.where(pressure_loss < 0, 0, pressure_loss)`.  But also note that sympy doesn't work with numpy arrays nor functions.

Comment: The inequality fails to evaluate because `pressure_loss` is `-93633.4332255447*x**2` and it isn't possible to evaluate that without some knowledge of the possible values of `x`. If you do `x,y = symbols('x,y', positive=True)` then this will pass but then I get an error because I don't have "fluids" installed.